# Rename file directories recursively using bash on windows

Tags: windows, bash, cmd

```
├── package-1
│   └── src
│       ├── controllers
│       ├── models
│       |── traits
│       └── views
├── package-2
│   └── src
│       ├── controllers
│       ├── models
│       |── traits
│       └── views
├── package-3
│   └── src
│       ├── controllers
│       ├── models
│       |── traits
│       └── views
```

I would like to recursively rename the folders `controllers` to `Controllers`, models and `Models`

From various articles e.g https://askubuntu.com/questions/56326/how-do-i-rename-a-directory-via-the-command-line and posts I can see that I need to use `rm` So I ran below command

```sh
for i in */src/controllers/; 
  do  mv $i /Controllers/; 
done
```

Below is the error I am facing

```
mv: cannot move 'laravel-files/src/controllers/' to '/Controllers/controllers': Directory not empty
mv: cannot move 'laravel-guardian-admissions/src/controllers/' to '/Controllers/controllers': Directory not empty
mv: cannot move 'laravel-guardians/src/controllers/' to '/Controllers/controllers': Directory not empty
mv: cannot move 'laravel-lms/src/controllers/' to '/Controllers/controllers': Directory not empty
mv: cannot move 'laravel-permissions-and-roles/src/controllers/' to '/Controllers/controllers': Directory not empty
mv: cannot move 'laravel-procurements/src/controllers/' to '/Controllers/controllers': Directory not empty
mv: cannot move 'laravel-school-accounts/src/controllers/' to '/Controllers/controllers': Directory not empty
mv: cannot move 'laravel-school-curriculum/src/controllers/' to '/Controllers/controllers': Directory not empty
mv: cannot move 'laravel-school-exams/src/controllers/' to '/Controllers/controllers': Directory not empty
mv: cannot move 'laravel-school-infrastructures/src/controllers/' to '/Controllers/controllers': Directory not empty
mv: cannot move 'laravel-school-streams/src/controllers/' to '/Controllers/controllers': Directory not empty
```

Kindly assist in pointing to where I am going wrong in the implementation

Comment: @anubhava same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to the leading `/` in `mv $i /Controllers/` you move every `$i` to the very same directory, that is a directory named `Controllers` on the very top of your filesystem.

Either `cd` into each directory and use a relative path (`cd "$i/.."; mv "$i" Controllers; cd -`) or modify the paths using bash's parameter expansion:

```
for i in */src/controllers/; do
  mv "$i" "${i/\/c/\/C}"
done
```

`${i/\/c/\/C}` replaces the first `/c` by `/C`.

Comment: This seems to be deleting the directories `deleted:    academic-year/src/controllers/AcademicYearApiController.php
        deleted:    academic-year/src/controllers/AcademicYearController.php
        deleted:    academic-year/src/controllers/AcademicYearUnitLevelController.php
        deleted:    gender/src/controllers/GenderApiController.php
        deleted:    gender/src/controllers/GenderController.php
        deleted:    laravel-data-sync/src/Controllers/DataSyncController.php`
`

Comment: I tested the command on exactly your example file structure, see https://onlinegdb.com/peej3HG7c. Are you sure the directories were deleted. I don't think `mv` can even print the message `deleted: ...` (at least my version does not contain such a string). Could it be that you have directory that is literally named `deleted: academic-year`?

Comment: Thanks, I think my earlier commands had deleted the files, I did a `git reset` and used your command, It worked like a charm, thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

If you have `GNU parallel` installed, you can try :

```
find . -regextype posix-extended -regex '.*/(controlers|models|traits|views)' | 
    parallel echo mv {} {= 's[(.*/)(.+)][${1} . ucfirst($2)]e' =}
```

remove `echo` if the result is expected.

Comment: Thanks for your solution, never used `GNU parallel` but will make sure to have a look at it